# Soft question. Affinity propagation

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

Does affinity propagation work well for for multidimensional data? While I was reading about it I couldn't find much information on this topic and all the examples I've seen we about 2D data. Could it be that Affinity propagation is still good for 3D and 4D data but is bad for 10+ dimensions? I am quite sorry for asking a question that could probably by myself after doing a research on the Internet, but I got to say that I am a very definition of newbie and all the information I've found was rather obscure to me. Don't want to make a false conclusion.